# how to display json data in wpf (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i have a wpf im working on I've never done wpf but I cant seem to get the json data from an API show as its just saying null, my code is but its just saying null in winforms I usually put this in the form load but wpf user control doesn't have a form load I tried it in the

```
public UserControl1(){

}
```

but that didn't work as its returning null any suggestions.

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var users = "API link";
label.Content = users;
```

Comment: What is returning null? You haven't even initiated a request in the code you have shown

Comment: its saying the label is null but the var isn't the API has data init so I'm a little confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you do all that after the `InitializeComponent();` call in your constructor ?

Once the `label` variable is set, then you can use it.

Comment: thank you that worked i didnt know code had to be after the init part